# How can I add alert when invite email is sent out?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my JavaScript code for sending invite email to others.
how/where can I add alert when invite email is sent successful.
The alert "your email is sent"

```
async function invitePeopleToMyTeam(){
    let [invites,invite_statuses] = [[],$Q('.invitation-data.invite-access').slice(0,20)];

    $Q('.invitation-data.invite-email').slice(0,20).map((i,ind)=>{
        if(~i.value.search(/.+@.+\..+/gi)){
            invites.push({
                email:i.value.trim().toLowerCase(),
                status:invite_statuses[ind].options[invite_statuses[ind].selectedIndex].innerHTML.slice(0,1).toLowerCase()
        });
        }else{
            invite_statuses[ind] = null;
        }
    });

    for(let i=0,il=invites.length; i<il; i++){
        if(invites[i] === null){
            invites.split(i,1);
            il--;
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        if(invites[i].status == null || invites[i].status == ""){
            invites[i].status = "m";
        }
    }
    if(invites.length===0 || invites.filter(e=>e).length===0){
        alert('There don\'t seem to be any e-mails in your invite list. Please review and try again.');
        return false;
    }
    
    let sql = `./invitePeople.cfc?method=sendInvite`;
    let params = {"invites" : invites};

    let result = await fetch(sql, {
        method:"post",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(params)
    })
    .then(resp => resp.text())
    .then(resp=>{console.log(resp); return resp})
    .then(r=>{
        $Q('.invitation-data.invite-email').slice(0,20).map((i,ind)=>{
        i.value= "";
    });
    })
    .catch(e=>console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: After `i.value= "";`

Comment: It works! But the alert window cannot close. It will always be here even I click "ok".

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add "finally"

```
let result = await fetch(sql, {
        method:"post",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(params)
    })
    .then(resp => resp.text())
    .then(resp=>{console.log(resp); return resp})
    .then(r=>{
        $Q('.invitation-data.invite-email').slice(0,20).map((i,ind)=>{
        i.value= "";
    })
    .finally(resp => alert('email sent')); // <<<<< here
    })
    .catch(e=>console.log(e));
```